# chrome version 116.0.5845.110 - ChromeDriverManager not loading

Tags: python, macos, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am having problems with Selenium ChromeDriverManager. I have just updated google chrome on my Mac to version `116.0.5845.110`. and is not working. The versions are different, but didn't even find an oldest chrome version to download. Anyone could help, please?
I have tried:

```
driver_path = ChromeDriverManager(version='114.0.5735.16').install()
driver_path = ChromeDriverManager(version='115.0.835.40').install()
driver_path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
```

Comment: What version of selenium and web driver manager are you using? Also, share the error stack.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome browser team has introduced new [Chrome For Testing](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) for Automation Testing specially and If you are using Chrome version 115 or newer, please look into the [Chrome for Testing availability dashboard](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/).

You face the above error because WebDriverManager don't know about where to find compatible driver for version 115.x and newer. Now selenium 4.11.0 added new driver path. So just update your Selenium version to latest and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can now download the chromedriver from the following website:
[Refer the link](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/)I can see chromedriver 116 is now available there.

I hope this helps!